# Can someone give an example which satisfies the following conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}$ be a continuous convex function such that $f(0)=0,\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\alpha<\infty$

My examples: if I choose $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{k},k>0$, then it will hold, but I need an example other than this.Thanks

Comment: Take for $f$ a linear function plus a function that goes to zero, e.g. $e^{-x}$.

Comment: You have said $f(x)=e^{-x}$ but it does not satisfies $f(0)=0$ condition

Comment: Okay, then take something like $f(x) = \alpha x + xe^{-x}$. There are so many choices.

Comment: $f(x)=\alpha x+x g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is any function satisfying $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=0$, $g(x)\geq 0$ and such that $f(x)$ is convex.

Answer (score 1):

Examples are
\begin{equation}
f(x) = x - \log(x+1)
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
g(x) = x + e^{-x} - 1
\end{equation}